# Cannot refresh 1 cell in UICollectionview iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have added 1 new cell in my `UICollectionView`, but it only refreshes after I scroll down and scroll to top, and that cell will be appeared. I want it will appeare immediately after inserting a new cell, without scrolling. I tried the following code. Please help me to correct it.

```
[self performBatchUpdates:^{

        self.arrayWithIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];

        [self.arrayWithIndexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath
                                             indexPathForRow:_numberOfItemsInCollectionView -1
                                             inSection:SECTION_COUNT-1]];

        [self insertItemsAtIndexPaths:self.arrayWithIndexPaths];



        //prepare generate XML
         [self prepareForGenerateXML:selectedItemsArray andCameraMode:NO];

    } completion:nil];
```

Comment: Did you update the data source before calling `insertItemsAtIndexPaths`?

Comment: Yes, i have updated data source before  calling insertItemsAtIndexPaths.

Comment: You must update your data source before calling insertItemsAtIndexPaths. I don't see this being done anywhere in the code you posted.